# Parsing a JSON array of arrays using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I know this is rather simple but I'm stuck at it and I'd really like some help

Here's a JSON string I'm generating.

```
[{"field1":3,"field2":"5","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"field1":3,"field2":"8","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"field1":3,"field2":"6","field3":"value3"}]
```

How do I extract the value associated with field1?

And how do I access elements of each of the distinct arrays?

Comment: you'll have to parse the string into an array structure your programming language understands. Which language is that? (javascript, php, ...)

Comment: Your question is not answerable if you don't tell us which programming language you are using.

Comment: my bad. I want to use PHP to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code

```
$jsonString = '[{"field1":3,"field2":"5","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"field1":3,"field2":"8","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"field1":3,"field2":"6","field3":"value3"}]';

$json = json_decode($jsonString, true);

print_r($json);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (in Javascript)

```
var jsonData=[{"field1":3,"field2":"5","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"field1":3,"field2":"8","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"field1":3,"field2":"6","field3":"value3"}];
```

if you get response as text then use jsonData=JSON.parse(yourResponseText);

```
for(var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
alert('your required val:'+jsonData[i].field1);
}
```

In php

```
$data = json_decode($json);//$json is your json data

foreach ($data as $item) {
  echo $item->field1
}
```

Comment: would you be able to help me with a PHP solution?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627901/485790

```
console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(' [{"field1":3,"field2":"5","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"field1":3,"field2":"8","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"field1":3,"field2":"6","field3":"value3"}]').field1);
```

Comment: could you help me with doing this in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

In php way

```
$jsonString = '[{"field1":3,"field2":"5","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"field1":3,"field2":"8","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"field1":3,"field2":"6","field3":"value3"}]';

$json = json_decode($jsonString, true);

foreach($json as $item){
   echo $item['field1'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In php you can:

```
$json = json_decode($_GET['variable'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
var json = '[{"field1":3,"field2":"5","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"field1":3,"field2":"8","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"field1":3,"field2":"6","field3":"value3"}]';
    $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(json), function () {
        alert(this['field1']);
        alert(this['field2']);
        alert(this['field3']);
        alert(this['field4']);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple array of json objects. so with jquery

```
var jsonArray = JSON.parse("your string");
   for(var int i=0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++){
     var jsonObject = jsonArray[i];
     Console.log(jsonObject.field1)
   }
```